# How to Retrieve all document from mongodb and show all data in HTML (Flask)

Tags: python, html, flask, pymongo

I'm trying to get data from mongodb and show results in HTML table,
it's working when I get one data by `find_one({})` but when get entire data with `find({})` the get error

`pymongo.errors.InvalidOperationpymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot set options after executing query`

I get table header by following code and restore it in `header` and show it without problem

```
resultdb = mongo.db.mydb.find({})
for itm in resultdb:
    header.append(itm)
```

issue raise when iterating for data to show `table boady`
HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-hover ">
        
        <tr>
            {% for itms in resultdb.items() %}
            <th> {{ itms[0] }} </th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {% for itms in resultdb.items() %}
            <td> {{ itms[1] }} </td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        </table>
```

*I'm using pymongo in flask

Is there any way to show all document in HTML table?

Comment: Does this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550144/pymongo-errors-invalidoperation-cannot-set-options-after-executing-query) answer your question? Basically, it's not a dictionary but rather a cursor object that's returned.

Comment: @JustLudo I had read the post, and try to change `pymongo.cursor` to `list` but not able to show it in HTML table

Comment: Maybe put in a debug statement and check the contents of the list and the structure of it all.